# How to Deploy MERN stack application on heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, heroku, create-react-app

I have made one `MERN (i.e-Mongo,Express,React,Node.js)` application and wants to deploy on Heroku. I created the react App using `create-react-app` and folder structure is given below.

**React-frontend**

```
     ---->Node_modules

     ----->Public

    ------->src

    ------->package.json

   ---------> readme.md
```

**React-backend:**

```
     ----->Node_modules

     ------>config

    -------->Controller

   ---------->route

  ------------>server.js

   ----------->package.json
```

Here I have other project for `NOde.js and MongoDB` operation and its instance (`e.g.http://localhost:8888`) is called from `React-frontend` to deal with the database. I need steps to deploy the total application into Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to deploy the app using the Heroku Node.js buildpack:

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs

It sounds like you're pretty new to Heroku, so read the README for that repo thoroughly, including the documentation for [Getting Started on Heroku with Node.js](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction).

Using Mongo with Heroku will require using one of the several MongoDB [add-ons](https://elements.heroku.com/addons).

Comment: what addons should I use mlab is discontinued